# unable to create AKS cluster using "UserDefinedRouting" using terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I'm Setting up AKS cluster using userDefinedRouting with existing subnet and route table which are associated with network security group. Here is my code snippet.

```
provider "azurerm" {
    version = "~> 2.25"
    features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "aks" {
    name     = var.resource_group
}

#fetch existing subnet 
data "azurerm_subnet" "aks" {
    name                 = var.subnetname
    virtual_network_name = var.virtual_network_name
    resource_group_name  = var.vnet_resource_group
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "k8svmnic" {
    name                = "k8svmnic"
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.aks.name
    location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.aks.location

    ip_configuration {
        name                          = "internal"
        subnet_id                     = data.azurerm_subnet.aks.id
        private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
        private_ip_address            = var.k8svmip #"10.9.56.10"
    }
}

resource "azurerm_availability_set" "k8svmavset" {
    name                         = "k8svmavset"
    location                     = data.azurerm_resource_group.aks.location
    resource_group_name          = data.azurerm_resource_group.aks.name
    platform_fault_domain_count  = 3
    platform_update_domain_count = 3
    managed                      = true
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "k8svmnsg" {
    name                  = "k8vm-nsg"
    resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.aks.name
    location              = data.azurerm_resource_group.aks.location

    security_rule {
        name                            = "allow_kube_tls"
        protocol                        = "Tcp"
        priority                        = 100
        direction                       = "Inbound"
        access                          = "Allow"
        source_address_prefix           = "VirtualNetwork"
        destination_address_prefix      = "*"
        source_port_range               = "*"
        #destination_port_range          = "443"
        destination_port_ranges         = ["443"]
        description                     = "Allow kube-apiserver (tls) traffic to master"
    }
    
    security_rule {
        name                            = "allow_ssh"
        protocol                        = "Tcp"
        priority                        = 101
        direction                       = "Inbound"
        access                          = "Allow"
        source_address_prefix           = "*"
        destination_address_prefix      = "*"
        source_port_range               = "*"
        #destination_port_range          = "22"
        destination_port_ranges         = ["22"]
        description                     = "Allow SSH traffic to master"
    }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "k8svmnicnsg" {
    network_interface_id                = azurerm_network_interface.k8svmnic.id
    network_security_group_id           = azurerm_network_security_group.k8svmnsg.id
}


resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "k8svm" {

    name                            = "k8svm"
    resource_group_name             = data.azurerm_resource_group.aks.name
    location                        = data.azurerm_resource_group.aks.location
    size                            = "Standard_D3_v2"
    admin_username                  = var.admin_username
    disable_password_authentication = true
    availability_set_id             = azurerm_availability_set.k8svmavset.id
    
    network_interface_ids = [
        azurerm_network_interface.k8svmnic.id,
        ]

    admin_ssh_key {
        username        = var.admin_username
        public_key      = var.ssh_key
    }

    os_disk {
        caching              = "ReadWrite"
        storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
        disk_size_gb         = 30
    }

    source_image_reference {
        publisher = "microsoft-aks"
        offer     = "aks"
        sku       = "aks-engine-ubuntu-1804-202007"
        version   = "2020.07.24"
    }

}

resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "k8svm-disk" {
    name                    = "${azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.k8svm.name}-disk"
    location                = data.azurerm_resource_group.aks.location
    resource_group_name     = data.azurerm_resource_group.aks.name
    storage_account_type    = "Standard_LRS"
    create_option           = "Empty"
    disk_size_gb            = 512

}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "k8svm-disk-attachment" {
    managed_disk_id         = azurerm_managed_disk.k8svm-disk.id
    virtual_machine_id      = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.k8svm.id
    lun                     = 5
    caching                 = "ReadWrite"
}
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "aks" {
    name                = "akspip"
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.aks.name
    location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.aks.location
    allocation_method   = "Static"
    sku = "Standard"
    depends_on = [azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment.k8svm-disk-attachment]
}
resource "azurerm_route_table" "aks"{
    name                          = "aks" #var.subnetname
    resource_group_name           = data.azurerm_resource_group.aks.name
    location                      = data.azurerm_resource_group.aks.location
    disable_bgp_route_propagation = false

    route {
            name                    = "default_route"
            address_prefix          = "0.0.0.0/0"
            next_hop_type           = "VirtualAppliance"
            next_hop_in_ip_address  = var.k8svmip
    }

    route {
            name                = var.route_name
            address_prefix      = var.route_address_prefix
            next_hop_type       = var.route_next_hop_type
    }


}
resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "aks" {
    subnet_id      = data.azurerm_subnet.aks.id
    route_table_id = azurerm_route_table.aks.id
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "aks" {
    subnet_id                 = data.azurerm_subnet.aks.id
    network_security_group_id = var.network_security_group
}
resource "null_resource" "previous" {}

resource "time_sleep" "wait_90_seconds" {
    depends_on = [null_resource.previous]

    create_duration = "90s"
}

# This resource will create (at least) 30 seconds after null_resource.previous
resource "null_resource" "next" {
    depends_on = [time_sleep.wait_90_seconds]
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
    name                    = data.azurerm_resource_group.aks.name
    resource_group_name     = data.azurerm_resource_group.aks.name
    location                = data.azurerm_resource_group.aks.location
    dns_prefix              = "akstfelk"   #The dns_prefix must contain between 3 and 45 characters, and can contain only letters, numbers, and hyphens. It must start with a letter and must end with a letter or a number.
    kubernetes_version      = "1.18.8"
    private_cluster_enabled = false
    node_resource_group     = var.node_resource_group
    
    #api_server_authorized_ip_ranges = [] #var.api_server_authorized_ip_ranges
    default_node_pool {
        enable_node_public_ip   = false
        name                    = "agentpool" 
        node_count              = var.node_count
        orchestrator_version    = "1.18.8"
        vm_size                 = var.vm_size
        os_disk_size_gb         = var.os_disk_size_gb
        vnet_subnet_id          = data.azurerm_subnet.aks.id
        type                    = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
    }

    linux_profile {
        admin_username = var.admin_username
        ssh_key {
            key_data = var.ssh_key
        }
    }
    service_principal {
        client_id     = var.client_id
        client_secret = var.client_secret
    }

    role_based_access_control {
        enabled = true
    }
    network_profile {
        network_plugin     = "kubenet"
        network_policy     = "calico"
        dns_service_ip     = "172.16.1.10"
        service_cidr       = "172.16.0.0/16"
        docker_bridge_cidr = "172.17.0.1/16"
        pod_cidr           = "172.40.0.0/16"
        outbound_type      = "userDefinedRouting"
        load_balancer_sku  = "Standard"

        load_balancer_profile {
            outbound_ip_address_ids = [ "${azurerm_public_ip.aks.id}" ]

        }
        # load_balancer_profile {
        #     managed_outbound_ip_count = 5
        #     #effective_outbound_ips    = [ azurerm_public_ip.aks.id ]
        #     outbound_ip_address_ids   = []
        #     outbound_ip_prefix_ids    = []
        #     outbound_ports_allocated  = 0
            
        # }
    }
        addon_profile {
        aci_connector_linux {
            enabled = false
        }

        azure_policy {
            enabled = false
        }

        http_application_routing {
            enabled = false
        }

        kube_dashboard {
            enabled = false
        }

        oms_agent {
            enabled            = false
        }
    }
    depends_on = [azurerm_subnet_route_table_association.aks]
}
```

According to Azure doc it says: "By default, one public IP will automatically be created in the same resource group as the AKS cluster, if NO public IP, public IP prefix, or number of IPs is specified.

But in my case outbound connection not happening Hence cluster provision getting failed. I've even created another public Ip and trying through Loadbalancer profile but i'm getting below error.

```
Error: "network_profile.0.load_balancer_profile.0.managed_outbound_ip_count": conflicts with network_profile.0.load_balancer_profile.0.outbound_ip_address_ids
```

If i've removed loadbalancer_profile from script i'm getting below error

```
Error: creating Managed Kubernetes Cluster "aks-tf" (Resource Group "aks-tf"): containerservice.ManagedClustersClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidUserDefinedRoutingWithLoadBalancerProfile" Message="UserDefinedRouting and load balancer profile are mutually exclusive. Please refer to http://aka.ms/aks/outboundtype for more details" Target="networkProfile.loadBalancerProfile"
```

Kinldy help me where i'm missing .

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `UserDefineRouting`, you need to set the `network_plugin` as `azure` and put the AKS cluster inside the subnet with the user-defined router, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/egress-outboundtype#outbound-type-of-userdefinedrouting) is the description:

> The AKS cluster must be deployed into an existing virtual network with
> a subnet that has been previously configured.

And if the `network_plugin` is set to `azure`, then the vnet_subnet_id field in the default_node_pool block must be set and pod_cidr must not be set. You can find this note in [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/kubernetes_cluster.html).

**Update:**

It's a little more complex than you think, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/limit-egress-traffic#restrict-egress-traffic-using-azure-firewall) is the Network Architecture of it and steps to create it via CLI. This architecture requires explicitly sending egress traffic to an appliance like a firewall, gateway, proxy or to allow the Network Address Translation (NAT) to be done by a public IP assigned to the standard load balancer or appliance.

For the outbound, instead of a Public Load Balancer you can use an internal Load Balancer for internal traffic.

In addition, some steps you cannot achieve via the Terraform, for example, the Azure Firewall. Take a look at the steps and prepare the resources which you cannot achieve via the CLI.

Comment: As per your point and docs i've made the changes but still cluster provision getting failed due to outbound connectivity issue where as we were able to procure cluster using aks engine smoothly . Can you suggest if anything missed at my end.

Comment: @SivaSankaraRaoBacha  Any more updates for the question? Do you solve the problem?

Comment: Sorry for late response. i've gone though the docs and implementing with ILB . I'll update thread with the results asap.

Comment: @SivaSankaraRaoBacha Well, I'll wait for serial days. If you have any updates, please let me know.